# How to get userHomePath and groupHomePath to work in TYPO3 CMS 6.2.6

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have tried to get userHomePath and groupHomePath to work in TYPO3 CMS 6.2.6 but with no look.

I have configured the following in the install tool:

```
[BE][lockRootPath] = /var/www/SiteName/
[BE][userHomePath] = 1:users/
[BE][groupHomePath] = 1:groups/
[BE][userUploadDir] = /uploads
```

The prefix `1:` is the uid of the default, auto created File Storage `fileadmin`. In the `fileadmin` directory i have created the following filestructor.

```
fileadmin
    users
        1_admin
        2
    groups
        1
```

As i see it I have done everything right, but it still wont work.

[The documentation is a little outdated](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/AccessControl/MoreAboutFileMounts/Index.html) compared to what the install tool says:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple and I found it in: `EXT:core/Classes/Authentication/BackendUserAuthentication.php` line 1588

```
$path = $userHomeFilter . $this->user['uid'] . '_' . $this->user['username'] . $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['userUploadDir'];
```

What i learned here was that my directory structure and configuration did not match. `userUploadDir` is not, as i thought, a directory for upload but just a prefix for the home directory it self.

By setting:

```
[BE][userUploadDir] =
```

... everything worked.

I could of cause also create the `uploads` folder in every home directory but i did not see any reason for it.